# I can't use variables from my main script in another script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

OK so I have 2 scripts. One is the main script that does everything and then I have a script on a projectile prefab. I can call variables from the prefab script in the main script,  but when I try to call variables from the main script in the prefab script it won't let me drag the Canvas (which the main script is attached to) to the slot for the main script.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Is there something I don't know about Unity and accessing the main script variables?

EDIT: Some very rude people here claiming I am "unseasoned". I'll have you know this is the last place I go to for an issue I am having. Of course I looked all over the internet, actually took 4 hours of constant searching for answers and troubleshooting. This is different from all the other so-called "most common" question about unity. I never knew, or heard from anyplace that A PREFAB OBJECT CAN'T ACCESS OTHER VARIABLES FROM OTHER SCRIPTS, let alone use them in it's own scripts. I'm so sorry for trying to learn.

Comment: I feel I need more context here, the visible amount of the inspector you've given is very small.  You mention that the `Script_phase_1` is attached to a Canvas, but not shown that.

Comment: https://gyazo.com/265fcc8caae956fb623787023b2b47d1

Comment: Thanks.  I am, unfortunately, still stumped.

Comment: It's ok, I might have to redo the whole thing anyway if this doesn't work...

Comment: Another option, if `Script_phase_1` will only ever be instanciated once: create a public, static, field in the class that is equal to the instance (set in `Start()` or `Awake()`) and reference it that way.

Comment: That is not the case, I need to reference it every time the user scores a point to add 1 score.

Comment: Actually, my alternative would work great in that case: `Script_phase_1.mainGameScript.score++`

Comment: I'd make a method for that, @Draco18s cause that is a rather pungent code smell, but the principle between doing that and the method is the same.

Comment: Main sounds like a bad idea for a name.

Comment: Well, I figured out why I couldn't access the main script variables. The script I was trying to access it from was attached to a prefab, I tried accessing the main script from another normal game object and it worked. So there was my problem.

Comment: Yes, you can't assign prefab components to non-prefab fields.  Its because the prefab's components aren't instanced and once instanced, there's many of them.  Only the prefab *itself* can be assigned as a variable (as the source in a clone operation).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unity/C# Find object and get component](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22048835/unity-c-find-object-and-get-component)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make a reference in the prefab projectile object to the object containing the script. I suggest to do so when instantiating it. After that you can call GetComponent() to get your script. Secondly it allows you to do this automatically without exposing any public members and keep dragging stuff.

Comment: I had actually done this, I watched the default Unity videos and that helped. Thing is, I heard somewhere that the GetComponent() function is very "consuming" in terms of taking processor power. Anyway, I'll give you the "check" so people don't keep commenting. Thank you for your input.